# ul li $(this).text() shows nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

SOLVED! actually the problem was in $(document).ready(function(){//}); after i used it, it worked fine. thanks for your help and sorry because of such silly mistake.

I'm trying to get selected li from bootstrap dropdown menu. It works but when i want to get the text of selected li, it shows nothing.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        <font id="dropdownMenu" >inch</font>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul id="dropdownList" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">cm</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">mm</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#dropdownList li').click(function () {
    console.log($(this).text());
    document.getElementById('dropdownMenu').innerHTML = $(this).text();
});
```

May i know why it's not working?

Thanks!

Comment: I just confused and wrongly answered. Never mind. But your code is working right? https://jsfiddle.net/ku99c8ad/1/ `.text()` will fetch all the text nodes of an element, even it is available in its deepest descendant.

Comment: thanks for your check but it's weird it's not working in my code @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Comment: `<font>` ? Dude, it's 2016.

Comment: However, if you use jQuery, use it as long as you can, but mixing pure JS / jQuery syntax makes things less readable. e.g. : `document.getElementById('dropdownMenu').innerHTML = $(this).text();` = `$('#dropdownMenu').html($(this).text());`

Comment: Can you give us your configuration ? (OS, browser, version) ?

Comment: os x version 10.11 , safari version 9.0 @enguerranws

Comment: I just tested it, Safari seems to bug with JSFiddle (sandbox error in the console). https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/ku99c8ad/ is working anyway (look the unit changing in the DOM).

Answer (score 0):

Get the text of an anchor tag inside. That's the element with text.

```
$('#dropdownList li').click(function () {
    console.log($(this).find('a').text());
    document.getElementById('dropdownMenu').innerHTML = $(this).find('a').text();
});
```

Comment: even though it's right what you say but still console.log shows nothing. i wonder if the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Try with find() instead of children(). already updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/ku99c8ad/)

```
$('#dropdownList li').click(function () {
    console.log($(this).text());
    $('#dropdownMenu').text($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: $('#dropdownList li a').click( function() {...});

Comment: @Michelem Same for me.

Comment: it works in JSFiddle but not working in my code @Michelem

Comment: i checked in jsfiddle. it's not bootstrap dropdown menu. it's just a menu. is it matter or not? @Michelem

Answer (score 0):

You should try to limit DOM reading/writing, like using `.find()` and the `.text()` etc. I would add some data in the markup

HTML:

```
<ul id="dropdownList" class="dropdown-menu">
  <li data-value="inch"><a href="#">inch</a></li>
  <li data-value="cm"><a href="#">cm</a></li>
  <li data-value="mm"><a href="#">mm</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('#dropdownList li').click(function () {
  console.log($(this).data('value'))
})
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y62287wu/)**

Two things:

- The `data-*` are valid HTML5 tags that you can use to fit your needs.
- Don't re-read the DOM for each clicks `var dropdownValue = $('#value')`.

Comment: even though it's right what you say but still console.log shows nothing. i wonder if the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I just posted a JS Fiddle, if this doesn't work, your problem is somewhere else.